# yyyy-MM-dd HH24:mm:ss timeStamp using Spark SQL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there is any equivalant  function to convert this kind of SQL timestamp using spark sql.

```
    TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, "yyyy-MM-dd HH24:mm:ss)

    TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, "yyyyMMddHHmmss)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
select date_format(current_timestamp(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
select date_format(current_timestamp(), "yyyyMMddHHmmss");
```